# Can the auto-increment value for a table be less than the maximum id?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

And if so, what happens when it reaches an id that is already in use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Nope, it cannot (though for innodb the value can be less than it was before server restart, but still more than the maximum value in the table)
2. <strike>You get warning and cannot insert anything else in the table</strike> (I read it as s a question "what happens when autoincrement reaches the maximum possible value")